# How do I use DTOs to consume a REST API in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, oop, dto, guzzle

I have an API to consume for a service that provides finance quotations on used cars. My app is written in PHP and I have Guzzle 5 added via Composer.

I have used other APIs previously that have take XML or just an Array of POST parameters to send, but this one is more complex.

This API uses DTO objects and the documentation says this:

```
relies heavily on DTOs to carry data between client and server. The following
sections detail the DTOs. Each web service will serialise and transfer them in their own
formats/methods. It is the responsibility of the client application to correctly construct requests and
parse responses. It is suggested that object serialization and deserialization be used for easier usage.
```

So I have no idea how to achieve this with Guzzle. Some of the enumeration types are things such as "RequestAssetMotorVehicle". Would you use StdClass or Arrays doing this in PHP? Or classes? How would I serialise it?

[Guzzle Docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html)

Comment: Can we have a link to the API's documentation ? Or maybe a dump of a working request ?

Answer (score 1):

Without the API's documentation this is difficult to express. But I'll try. We'll use a generic JSON based REST API

DTO standards are usually per company and sometimes per application. In short: A DTO is a serialized object.

Let's say this is a POST request ( we're creating a new user)

```
{
   'name':'john',
   'foo':'bar',
   'site':'stackoverflow.com'
}
```

That JSON is a DTO. Now let's do a GET

```
{
   'error':false,
   'results':2,
   'data': [{'name':'john','foo':'bar','site':'stackoverflow.com'}, 
             {'name':'mark','foo':'bar','site':'notstackoverflow.com'}]
}
```

the array of 'data' is an array of DTO.

So what the dox are telling you is that you need to familiarize your application with the API by creating a layer for that data to pass through to be formed into objects on your side and the same layer should take an object and turn it into a DTO. In some cases you can just handle the responses from API's with simple code, however in a situation were the GET request would return more than 10 results you are going to want to parse it with some class. Essentially creating an ORM for DTOs.

As far as guzzle goes: set the body to what ever the results of pushing the data through the layer.

```
public function createUserWithSomeApi()
{
    $g= new \Guzzle\Client();
    $response = $g->post('http://api.some.place/v1/users', [
                'body' => (new strangeApiDtoParser)->prepare($new_user_data)  
                                         ]);
    return ApiDtoParser::fromDTO($response->getBody());
}
```

And receive

```
public function getUsersFromSomeApi()
{
    $g= new \Guzzle\Client();
    $response = $g->get('http://api.some.place/v1/users', [
             'query' => ['foo' => 'bar']
                          ]);
    return ApiDtoParser::fromDTO($response->getBody());
}
```

Now your parser:

```
class ApiDtoParser
{
    public static function fromDto($raw)
    {
        $returnArray=[];
        $decoded =json_decode($data,true);
        foreach($decoded as $one){
            $obj = new DtoObj;
            foreach ($one as $key => $value) {
                $meth = "set". ucfirst(strtolower($key));
                $obj->{$meth}($var);
            }
            $returnArray[]=$obj;
        }
        return $returnArray;
    }
}
```

Judging by the context of you excerpt, You will need to create a request based parser though